# Regex needed for extracting filename from given string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
FileInfo(path=u'dbfs:/mnt/adls/ess/les-json1.json', name=u'les-json1.json', size=54L)
```

I need to extract the following portions of this string

```
/mnt/adls/ess/les-json1.json
```

I am using Python and the string is always the same strcuture.

Comment: That looks like a instance of a `FileInfo`, not a string... what have you tried?

Comment: I don't think regexp is necessary here. You can run do `path.split(':')[1]`

Comment: `re.search('dbfs:(.+?)', yourstring)`

Comment: 7 downvotes! What is the expectation? If i knew the answer, i wouldnt have posted it here. And sometimes just a hint on a direction could help solving such an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Sayse is right. Its a FileInfo Object and therefore i could use it like this. Sorry for bothering you for this simple solution.

```
for val in files: 
  print (val.path)
```

and for a filepath without dbfs:/

```
for val in files: 
  print(val.path.partition(':')[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if your string looks like xxxx:/some/path then the simplest method would be to use [`str.split()`](https://kite.com/python/docs/__builtin__.str.split) method:

```
fi: FileInfo
fi.path.split(':', 1)[1]  # our string
```

Comment: `fi.path.partition(':')[2]` is a more efficient way of doing `str.split(..., 1)`...

Comment: import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("s = 'dbfs:/mnt/adls/ess/les-json1.json';s.partition(':')[2]"))
    print(timeit.timeit("s = 'dbfs:/mnt/adls/ess/les-json1.json';s.split(':')[1]"))

That's right